# Select tables matching condition from all tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select for all tables with columns that contain the word `deposit` from a list of all tables when the owner is like `bi`. How can I implement this?

For example, I can select all tables and owner:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER LIKE '%BI';
```

But I want to then select all tables from `table_name` and run a query to find those columns that are type character and contain the string `deposit`. This I cannot understand how to do.

UPDATE:
The following query worked:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE OWNER LIKE '%BI' 
AND DATA_TYPE 
LIKE '%NUMBER' 
AND COLUMN_NAME 
LIKE '%DEPOSIT%';
```

Comment: Why you mention "are type character" and then search with NUMBER.

Comment: @Gnqz I just copied my last working example because I already tested with character but made the change and my last change included number.

Comment: @Workingdollar If you have any (quoted identifiers)[https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html] for column names, you will need to convert the column name to uppercase for the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the data_type to `varchar%` (to catch `varchar` and `varchar2`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
  FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS TBLS
 WHERE UPPER(TBLS.OWNER)  LIKE '%BI'
   AND UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE '%DEPOSIT%'
   AND UPPER(DATA_TYPE)   LIKE 'VARCHAR%';
```

Comment: Question on this: because some tables have multiple columns with deposit, how do I just grab a unique selection of these tables?

Comment: With `SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME` if you want just the tables